# How to speed up itertools combinations?

Tags: python, numpy, combinations, cython, levenshtein-distance

As part of my own research on genotype networks, I have a block of code in which I am trying to construct a single-difference network from a list of strings. The procedure is as such:

1. Iterate over all pairwise combinations of strings.
2. If the strings differ by a single position, then draw an edge between them in the network.
3. If they don't differ by a single position, then pass.

The block of code I have right now is as such:

```
from itertools import combinations
import Levenshtein as lev # a package that wraps a C-implemented levenshtein distance
import networkx as nx
strings = [...list of strings...]

G = nx.Graph()

for (s1, s2) in combinations(strings, 2):
    if s1 not in G.nodes():
        G.add_node(s1)
    if s2 not in G.nodes():
        G.add_node(s2)

    if lev.distance(s1, s2) == 1:
        G.add_edge(s1, s2)
```

There's clearly no way to improve the computational complexity of the graph construction procedure - it will always be `O(n**2)`. At least, in my limited knowledge, that's what I think - perhaps I'm wrong?

That said, given the normal scale of the number of comparisons that I need to make (~approx. 2000-5000), if I can get a few orders of magnitude speedup, overall, then the real-world computing time would be still acceptable - with the current Python implementation, it takes ~days to construct the graph. With the correct imports (not stated below), I have tried a Cython implementation below, but could not figure out how to make it faster:

```
cpdef cython_genotype_network(sequences):

    G = nx.Graph()
    cdef:
        unicode s1
        unicode s2

    for (s1, s2) in combinations(sequences, 2):
        if lev.distance(s1, s2) == 1:
            G.add_edge(s1, s2)

    return G
```

Particularly, Cython expects `bytes`, not `str` for `s1` and `s2`. That block of code throws an error.

So... I come to my two questions:

- Q1: Will the Cython implementation help? And how do I fix the bytes vs. str error?
- Q2: Is it possible to do this problem using `numpy` instead? It's easy to convert from a `numpy` matrix to NetworkX; however, I can't seem to figure out how to broadcast the Levenshtein distance function across an n-by-n empty matrix where the each row and column corresponds to a string.

**UPDATE 1: How to generate sample data**

To generate strings:

```
from random import choice

def create_random_nucleotides_python(num_nucleotides):
    """
    Creates random nucleotides of length num_nucleotides.
    """

    sequence = ''

    letters = ['A', 'T', 'G', 'C']

    for i in range(num_nucleotides):
        sequence = sequence + choice(letters)

    return sequence


def mutate_random_position(string):
    """
    Mutates one position in the nucleotide sequence at random.
    """

    positions = [i for i in range(len(string))]
    pos_to_mut = choice(positions)

    letters = ['A', 'T', 'G', 'C']

    new_string = ''
    for i, letter in enumerate(string):
        if i == pos_to_mut:
            new_string = new_string + choice(letters)
        else:
            new_string = new_string + letter

    return new_string


# Create 100 Python srings by mutating a first sequence, then randomly choosing stuff to mutate a single position.
base_sequence = create_random_nucleotides_python(1000)

sequences = [base_sequence]

for i in range(99):
    sequence = choice(sequences)
    mutseq = mutate_random_position(sequence)
    sequences.append(mutseq)
```

Comment: What is `.nodes()`? it it is not a set it should be

Comment: Based on the `networkx` documentation, `Graph.nodes()` returns a list, but the underlying implementation is a dictionary.

Comment: That is an `O(n)` lookup each time then, I presume the nodes are the keys?

Comment: Yes, I think that is correct.

Comment: Well either `if s1 not in G` or `if G.has_node(s1) ` should give you 0(1) lookups, I imagine `G.has_node` is syntactic sugar for `if s1 not in G` but I did not check

Comment: True. However, what I'm most interested is the edges - which are only drawn between two nodes if their strings differ by one letter. That requires a comprehensive (n(n-1))/2 search, which is n**2 complexity.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83345/discussion-between-ericmjl-and-padraic-cunningham).

Comment: Report: I was able to fix the bytes problem by declaring `s1` and `s2` as unicode. However, that still does not speed up the code.

Comment: Do you have some sample data handy to run a few tests?

Comment: I can provide the code that I used to generate the sequences. Allow me a few more minutes to copy/paste that code into the question.

Comment: Cool, I will work on a cython solution and drop a link when and if  I get something more efficient working

Comment: `cython` does not help much when it has to call `python` functions,

Comment: @hpaulj: that's what I observe as well. Is `numpy` a feasible alternative?

Comment: How do the  length of the strings fit into it, do they need to all be the same length?

Comment: They don't all have to be the same length. Part of it is that the sequences can undergo deletion or insertion.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding complexity:

You are considering each pair of strings. You don't need that. You can consider all 1-distance strings for each strings:

```
# I would start by populating the whole graph:
for s1 in strings:
    if s1 not in G.nodes():
        G.add_node(s1)
# Then compute the leven-1:
for s1 in strings:
    for s2 in variations(s1):
        if s2 in G.nodes():
            G.add_edge(s1, s2)
```

Now all your need is a `variations(string)` shorter than `O(n)`:

This returns all variations with a distance of 1. (only 1 edit|delete|insert)

```
def variations(string):
    for i in range(len(string)):
        # delete
        yield string[:i] + string[i+1:]
        # edit
        for l in 'ATGC':
            yield string[:i] + l + string[i+1:]
        # insert
        for l in 'ATGC':
            yield string[:i] + l + string[i:]

    # insert at the end
    for l in 'ATGC':
        yield string + l
```

Now, the complexity of that is `O(m^2)` (because of the string concat), where `m` is the size of the longest sequence. If it is known, it is a constant, and all that is now `O(1)`

If the sequences are all the same size, you can compute only the edits.

Else, you can sort your sequences from largest to smallest, and only compute edits and deletes.

Or, you can sort your strings by size, and instead of comparing all strings with all other, compare those that have a size difference of <= 1.

Comment: Interesting approach! The sequences are actually amino acid sequences of variable lengths (but not high variance in the lengths).

Comment: On that point of string size, how come if we know the max string length, the complexity is `O(1)`?

Comment: @ericmjl because it becomes a constant. If your string size is maxed by, say, 10 (works the same with 10000, though), then you know that there are 100 variations of the string, no matter how many strings you have in your pool. Which means that the overall algorithm is `O(n)`, where n is the number of strings, because if you have twice as many strings, the algorithm will take twice as much size. If the size of the string is unknown, though, it says a variable in the computation

Comment: now, from your `mutate_random_position` function, it does not seem that the strings change size, which is apparently 1000.

Comment: that is correct, and it holds only for the synthetic data. The real world data is much messier :) I'm testing different algorithms only on the synthetic data though.

Comment: One thing I just noticed: the levenshtein distance algorithm is usually O(m + d^ˆ2), where m is the length of the first string, and d the edit distance. That makes the code you posted in the question `O((m+d^2)*n^2)` (depending on the actual variations that have happened, `d` varies, but is guaranteed to be < m, so overall you can probably assume `O(m^2 * n^2)`). While the overall complexity of the solution I suggest is `O(m^2 * n)`

Comment: a different thing you could try, is this: initiate your graph by putting all sequence in the right place, using your algorithm for example. Then, every time you mutate a sequence by 1, reposition it in the graph. To do that, you only need to look at the neighbors and the neighbors' neighbors.

Answer (score 0):

Some thoughts about how the `cython` code might be faster

```
for (s1, s2) in combinations(sequences, 2):
    if lev.distance(s1, s2) == 1:
        G.add_edge(s1, s2)
```

I think `itertools.combinations` is compiled, so is, by itself, fast.  And you invoke it once, so the `for  ...` part is probably as fast as it comes.  Still, it wouldn't be hard to loop through `sequences` yourself in `cython`.

`lev.distance` appears to use compiled code.  Is it possible to import and invoke that code directly?  Look at the `lev` source.

I think `lev.distance` ends up calling a c function with signature:

```
distance_py(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
```

or more basically

```
lev_edit_distance(size_t len1, const lev_byte *string1,
              size_t len2, const lev_byte *string2,
              int xcost)
```

https://github.com/ztane/python-Levenshtein/blob/master/Levenshtein/_levenshtein.c

---

What does `G.add_edge` do?  Is there a simpler data structure where you could collect these 'edges'.  Maybe as a list of tuples?

Does `networkx` provide a way of adding nodes and edges in bulk?  Do you always have to use `add_node` and `add_edge`?  or can you give it a list nodes, and list of node pairs (tuples)?

---

Looks like a `graph` is a Python dictionary, or dictionary of dictionaries.

`networkx` lets you added a bunch of edges, via list of tuples:

```
>>> G.add_edges_from([(1,2),(1,3)])
```

http://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/tutorial/tutorial.html#edges

In the python code, this piece is probably unnecessary:

```
if s1 not in G.nodes():
    G.add_node(s1)
if s2 not in G.nodes():
    G.add_node(s2)
```

Just do:

```
G.add_nodes_from(strings)
```

http://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/tutorial/tutorial.html#nodes